# How To Test Dependency Injection Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I ran a coverage report on my jest tests and received this output.

```
File                  |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
  players.resolver.ts |    92.31 |      100 |    66.67 |    90.91 |                27 |
```

I went to investigate line 27 and it reads:

```
27: @Query(returns => GetPlayer)
28: async GetPlayer(@Args('id') id: PlayerInput): Promise<Player> {
29:    return await this.playerService.findOneById(id);
30:  }
```

My test is:

```
      const res = {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'First',
        lastName: 'Last',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      };

      const result: Promise<Player> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(res);
      });

      jest
        .spyOn(playersService, 'findOneById')
        .mockImplementation(() => result);

      const args = {
        id: '1',
      };

      expect(await playersResolver.GetPlayer(args)).toBe(res);
    });
```

I was thinking of something like:

`expect(res).toBeOfType(GetPlayer)` but couldn't find that in the Jest documentation. Is there a suite of tools for testing dependency injection like this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Is `.toBeInstanceOf(Class)` you want?

Comment: I don't think its an instance of.. The question was aimed at getting the decorator under that umbrella of covered tests.